# Can you find a series whose sum is $.... = (a) *\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I discovered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712599/can-you-prove-that-frac1n-frac1n2-frac1n3-frac1n-1/1712612?noredirect=1#comment3496072_1712612) that $ \frac{1}{n-1}= (n-1)^-1$ is the sum om a geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}.... = \frac{1}{n-1}$$

can you tell me if $(\sqrt{1-n})^-1$ $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-n}}$$

can be considered the result/sum of any kind of series, sequence, progression

Edit:

consider $|n| <1$,  specify what happens if we have a factor $a$ before the square root and, if you please,  case consider the particular case when the sum of the series is  $$0.7071 * \sqrt{\frac{1}{1-.99}}$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a}{2^n}=a$.

Comment: The notation is a little dangerous: observe that what you discovered in that link is true **only if** $\;|n|<1\;$ , and since $\;n\;$ usually denotes a natural number, or at least an integer one, this can be misleading very easily, in my opinion.

Comment: There are always infinitely many series that sums to any given expression. For example $a_1 = s$ with $a_2=a_3=\ldots=0$ has $\sum a_n = s$. Voting to close as the question has too many answers.

Comment: Yes it is. For any $k$ let the $k$'th term be $\sqrt{0.5}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-n}}$ and the rest zero. "The simplest one" is a highly subjective term. The reason is that too broad questions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 3):

$\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (a_{n}-a_{n+1})
=a_m
$,
so

$\begin{array}\\
\frac1{\sqrt{m}}
&=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}})\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}})\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}}{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}})}\\
&=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{n}+n\sqrt{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: If inside the square root, the result is scaled by $\sqrt{a}$, if outside the square root, scaled by $a$.

Comment: What do you call such a series? it is not  geometric it is a sum of square roots, right? so, has it got a particular name?

Comment: Nah. It's just a series. I kept on going to try to obfuscate the source as much as possible. It might make an interesting problem to prove thar the final series is equal to $\sqrt(m)$. To make it harder, set $m=2$ to hide the dependence on $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1}=S_{n+1}-S_{n}$ and you have the formula for $S_n$......

Answer (score 0):

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $|n|<1,$

$$\sqrt{\dfrac1{1-n}}=(1-n)^{-\frac12}=?$$

The $r+1(\ge0)$th term $$\dfrac{n^r1\cdot3\cdots2r-1}{2^r}=\dfrac{n^r}{4^r}\dfrac{(2r)!}{r!}$$

What happens if $|n|>1?$

Comment: If $n > 1$ you have to write $(n-1)^{-1/2} = n^{-1/2}(1-1/n)^{-1/2}$ and then expand.

Comment: @martycohen, True

Comment: @user11374, Why don't you replace $n$ with $0.99$

Comment: @user11374, See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws

Comment: I'd appreciate it you could make a concrete example showing what elements give the result of my example, that is **70.071** (.7 +(1/0.01))